# Scala 2.7 : reference is ambiguous (imported twice)

Tags: scala, ambiguous

In Scala 2.7, I want to use a method as a parameter of another method of the same class.

I have a class and objects which are companions:

```
class mM(var elem:Matrix){
    //apply a function on a dimension rows (1) or cols (2) 
    def app(func:Iterable[Double]=>Double)(dim : Int) : Matrix = {
        ...
    }
    //utility function
    def logsumexp(): Double = {...}
}

object mM{
    def apply(elem:Matrix):mM={new mM(elem)}
    def logsumexp(elem:Iterable[Double]): Double ={
         this.apply(elem.asInstanceOf[Matrix]).logsumexp()
    }
}
```

Normally I use logsumexp like this `mM(matrix).logsumexp` but if want to apply it to the rows I can't use `mM(matrix).app(mM.logsumexp)(1)`, I get the error:

```
error: reference to mM is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import mM
and import mM
```

What is the most elegant solution ? Should I change logsumexp() to another class ?

Thanks,=)

Comment: Are you using Scala 2.7? I tested it under 2.8 and it works fine.

Comment: Indeed, I'm using Scala 2.7 =)

Comment: This doesn't address the original question, but why are you casting an `Iterable[Double]` to `Matrix` with `asInstanceOf` instead of simply taking a `Matrix` as argument?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just downloaded 2.7 and tested your code and it still works. So, there must be something other wrong. Could you provide a minimal example which is a complete program and which is not compilable?

Answer (score 0):

I finally only used `new mM(matrix)` and not `mM(matrix)` statements inside my mM Class and avoided the error.

@Rex Kerr : You are right I changed the type to `Matrix`.

Thanks